# OpenGL ES 2.0 using multiple normal vectors per vertex

Tags: opengl-es, shader, vbo, normals

Obviously new to OpenGL I was wondering if it was possible to use a VBO with multiple normal vectors per vertice.  My current vertex array order looks like:

j = [x,y,z,r,g,b,a,n1x,n1y,n1z,n2x,n2y,n2z,n3x,n3y,n3z....]

This method requires the shaders to distinguish which normal vector to use, which is causing the problem.  Any suggestions would be great.

Also looking for tutorials on using multiple  IBO's and VBO's, most tutorials only seem to use one.

Comment: What problms does it cause where? Can you add these details please?

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's easier for us to answer your questions if you can be more specific about what kinds of problems you're having. What are you using multiple normals per vertex for, and what's going wrong with choosing them in the shader?

Answer (score 0):

You might make it work interleaved by supplying different strides to glVertexAttribPointer(), which is how it handles different amounts of data for the vertex and texture coordinates, for example.  Or, you could use separate VBOs for the vertex, normal and texture coordinates, rather than interleave them.

You can find better examples of using VBOs in the PowerVR SDK, which is a free download at:

http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/sdkdownloads/

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've found the easiest way is to just repeat the vertice whenever the normal of that vertice changes (aka it is a corner of a 3d object).  It makes the GLSL logic easier.  I will also look into the PowerVR SDK.